# How can I figure out if Realm exists

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I want to change the Realmconfiguration for an allready existing realm database. In my app I'm using until now:

```
new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).name("db10").build();
```

After publishing the app on Playstore I found out that I could use a custom Migration to change an already existing Database like so:

```
new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).name("db10"). schemaVersion(0).migration(new CustomMigration()).build();
```

But I can not change the Realmconfiguration for an already existing Database. If I try to open the existing Database with new Configuration I get :

```
IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.
```

So what I want to do now is 
 - create a new Database on the device with Migration feature
 - check if there is an old Database 
 - if there is an old Database on the Device copy the Content to the new Database and delete the old Database

Comment: Just giving them different names should work in that case? But why do you want to use 2 different configurations for the same file? Just using the later should work fine.

Comment: the problem is that user allready installed the first one and I don't want them to loose the data

Comment: The whole point of the migration is so that you don't lose the data.

Comment: Since the user will install a new app, it is fine to change the Configuration object itself. That will not change the underlying file in any way, only the actual Migration will do that.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior thanks yes found that out in the moment by own. I just forgot to change all my Realmconfiguration calls to the new one